# ASP.NET MVC Post with a href

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I have pager with the links, i want to use post instead of default redirect, because i need to pass some another values from the form. I set jquery post onclick like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mytable tfoot a").click(function() {
                  $.post($(this).attr("href"), $("form").serialize());
                  //return false; if i set that the page does not getting updated
    });
 });
```

But it is not completely overrides a href behavior, because first whats happens it is post action so that's good, but then form getting submitted once again.

My javascript does not override a href behavior completely.

May be some one have nay ideas about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to AJAXify a link is the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytable tfoot a').click(function() {
        $.post(this.href, $('form').serialize(), function(result) {
            alert('success');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Few things to verify:

- You are attaching the `.click` handler inside a `$(document).ready` as shown in my snippet.
- You are returning `false` from the `.click` handler in order to cancel the default action.
- The href of the anchor is pointing to an existing controller action.
- There is no exception being thrown when the action is invoked.
- Analyze with FireBug whether the AJAX request is sent and what does the server respond. This will allow you to see any potential error messages that might be thrown.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I set click inside document ready (updated) but if i put return false; the link stop working

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, what about the other points I highlighted in my answer? Most importantly what do you see in FireBug?

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, do you see the AJAX request/response? Look at `XHR` in the Network tab.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov actually with return false; it is sending post request to server but no response coming back may be because of different url?

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, there must always be a response from the server. And this response must be shown in the Chrome Developper Tools. Maybe it's a 404 because you used a wrong href, maybe it is a 500 because an exception is thrown, I have no way of knowing this, only you can debug your application.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Status Code:200 OK

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, so it seems everything is fine. What's the problem?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov request URL are different from the current url, i have page number in url if i click on the page link request going to happen but url not changed because current url and url after clicked on page link are different

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, you are doing an AJAX request and they happen asynchronously, you cannot expect the current url to change. In order to navigate to some other page you could use `window.location.href = 'some new address';` in the success callback of your AJAX request. But I am afraid that what you are doing is simply wrong. Why don't you directly submit the form to this new URL? Why not use a submit button instead of an anchor link which will do all this automatically without any javascript and AJAX?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov but the idea was to post form to another url and get response back, instead of redirect

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin, now I am really confused at what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov i agree with your comment about post buttons 100% because in MVC 3.0 grid helper i could not control pager so well, it is generating a hrefs by default, so i think i should use custom pager to do the thing.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov i have params in url(sorting order, page number) and some form inputs which is not url params so on controller i want both values from url and form as well that's why i was trying to do this crazy "a href" post.

Comment: @Vasya Pupkin: I think that part of the confusion is that you are saying that you want a response "back", while the response is actually the new page, and that you are saying "redirect" when you mean a regular request. If you want to post the form and simply arrive to that page, you should not use AJAX, you should simply post a form. See my answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you experience that it doesn't work, is because you are not doing what you think you are doing.

The `$.post` method doesn't post the form, it makes an AJAX call in the background. You can supply a callback method in the call that will be called when the response arrives, but as you have no callback method you simply ignore the response, so nothing seems to happen.

As you want to post the form you should not use the `$.post` method, instead you should use the `submit` method to send the form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#mytable tfoot a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // keeps the link from being activated
    var form = $("form");
    form.attr('action', $(this).attr("href"));
    form.attr('method', 'post');
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return false;` is actually vital to prevent the link being followed after the `$.post()` call.

Comment: Yep i know that but in my case link just not working if i put return false;

Comment: The link is supposed to not follow through though when you AJAXify it. That is the entire point of using that POST. If you need the page to go somewhere else after the POST, then that's an entirely different question I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post to another URL, and have the page go to that URL as part of the post, then the only solution is to place your data in input elements inside of a form who's action is the page you wish to post to.

You can do ajax posts, like you're doing, but that won't redirect the user to that page with the post data.  You are likely making this a lot harder than it has to be.